# Find the limit of $P_{\theta_n}\Big(\sqrt{n}(T_n-\mu(\theta_n))<z_\alpha \sigma(0)-\sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))\Big)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, weak-convergence

**Assumptions:** Consider a sample of i.i.d random variables $X_i$ $i=1,...,n$, where each $X_i$ is defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ be the parameter underlying the probability distribution of $X_i$, $P_{\theta}$.

(1) Let $\{\theta_n\}_n$ be a sequence of parameters such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\theta_n=0$.

(2) Let $\theta \rightarrow \mu(\theta)\in \mathbb{R}$ be a map differentiable at $0$ with derivative $\mu'(0)$.

(3) Let $\theta \rightarrow \sigma(\theta)\in \mathbb{R}$ be a map continuous at $0$.

(4) Define the statistic $T_n:=T(X_1,...,X_n)$ and assume $\sqrt{n} \frac{T_n-\mu(\theta_n)}{\sigma(\theta_n)}\overbrace{\rightarrow_d}^{P_{\theta_n}} N(0,1)$  $\forall \{\theta_n\}_n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

(5) Let $z_\alpha$ be the $(1-\alpha)$th quantile of the standard normal distribution.

**Statement:** I want to show that
$$
P_{\theta_n}\Big(\sqrt{n}(T_n-\mu(\theta_n))<z_\alpha \sigma(0)-\sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))\Big)=\Phi\Big(z_\alpha+o(1)-\sqrt{n}\theta_n\frac{\mu'(0)}{\sigma(0)}(1+o(1))\Big)
$$

**Attempt**:

(i) I think that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))=\mu'(0)$ using (1) and (2).

(ii) By  (3) and (4) $\sqrt{n}(T_n-\mu(\theta_n))\overbrace{\rightarrow_d}^{P_{\theta_n}} N(0,\sigma^2(0))$

(iii) $\sqrt{n}(T_n-\mu(\theta_n))+\sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))\overbrace{\rightarrow_d}^{P_{\theta_n}} N(\mu'(0),\sigma^2(0))$

(iv) hence, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P_{\theta_n}\Big(\sqrt{n}(T_n-\mu(\theta_n))<z_\alpha \sigma(0)-\sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))\Big)=\Phi\Big(z_\alpha-\frac{\mu'(0)}{\sigma(0)}\Big)$

(v) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: By Taylor expansion about zero,

$$
\mu(\theta_n)=\mu(0)+\mu'(0)(\theta_n-0)+o(\theta_n-0)\\
\iff\sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))=\sqrt{n}\mu'(0)\theta_n+\sqrt{n}o(\theta_n)\\
\iff \sqrt{n}(\mu(\theta_n)-\mu(0))=\sqrt{n}\theta_n\mu'(0)+\sqrt{n}\theta_n o(1)\\
$$

Furthermore, $\frac{\mu'(0)}{\sigma(0)}=o(1)$ is just a constant. Given the other stuff you have I think you can complete the steps.

Comment: To continue the steps and replace $P_{\theta_n}(\cdot)$ with $\Phi(\cdot)$, do I need to impose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}\theta_n=O(1)$ with a limit different from $\infty$?